# Why does `RSYNC_RSH` not work, but `--rsh` does?

Tags: rsync

Setting `RSYNC_RSH` is not working, but the `--rsh` option is.  Why?

`rsync` is correctly using the `--rsh` option:

```
$ rsync --rsh "echo" invalid invalid::invalid
rsync: server sent "invalid rsync --server --daemon ." rather than greeting
rsync error: error starting client-server protocol (code 5) at main.c(1657) [sender=3.1.3]
```

but I expected `RSYNC_RSH` would work the same, and it does not:

```
$ RSYNC_RSH=echo rsync invalid invalid::invalid
rsync: getaddrinfo: invalid 873: Name or service not known
rsync error: error in socket IO (code 10) at clientserver.c(127) [sender=3.1.3]
```

---

I have tried `rsync` versions 3.1.2-1+deb9u1 and 3.1.3-5.fc29.x86_64.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is working as designed.

You are using the rsync "daemon" syntax: `hostname::module`.  When you use this with `--rsh`, it connects to the server using the remote shell (e.g. `ssh`), but then uses `rsyncd.conf`.  When you use this *without* `--rsh`, it tries to make an unencrypted network connection to the rsync server on TCP port 873.

Setting `RSYNC_RSH` does not cause rsync "daemon" syntax to use a remote shell.

`RSYNC_RSH` is an "environment variable".  It is designed to be set for your entire environment.  It changes which remote shell rsync uses, when you are *not* using the rsync "daemon" syntax.  This was useful in ancient times, when there were several different remote shells, so rsync might not know which one you use most often.